# Trying to use DecimalFormat with Locale and variable decimal places

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am using decimal format to show prices with different locales.

My base format is:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
String cur_syl = dfs.getCurrencySymbol().toString();

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(cur_syl+"0.00");                     
total.setText(df.format(line_total));
```

This works for me and shows the correct currency symbol for the local. However, sometimes the fractional part goes to more than 2 places.. (because of unit of measurements conversions (leaves a real small part). The display shows 0.00 if the amount is really 0.005. I would like to only display the extra decimal places if there are values there. I don't really want to show 0.0050000 just to account for the amounts that are less than one-hundreth.

I've been through much of the help and web.. It's kind of confusing to me and I'm about to do a fancy code work around for this, but I'm sure there is a nice easy way to do what I need.

I would like to display numbers like this:

```
.05 = $0.05
.005 = $0.005
.0005 = $0.0005
```

If the program shows: $0.0005 = $0.00 then it will look like an error.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

Here is some example code using the "#" mask for  `DecimalFormat`.  The "#" mask will only display a number if one exists in that location.  You can use it on the lefthand side of the decimal also with a format like `#,##0.00`  That way the comma will only display if the number gets to the thousands, but a 0 will always be displayed in the ones position.

```
double line_total0 = 0.5;
double line_total1 = 0.05;
double line_total2 = 0.005;
double line_total3 = 0.0000005;

DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
String cur_syl = dfs.getCurrencySymbol().toString();

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(cur_syl + "0.00############");
System.out.println(df.format(line_total0));
System.out.println(df.format(line_total1));
System.out.println(df.format(line_total2));
System.out.println(df.format(line_total3));
```

Output:

```
$0.50
$0.05
$0.005
$0.0000005
```